# Decent tutorial on ember cli how to fetch JSON response

Tags: json, rest, ember.js, ember-cli

I've been wasting all my journey trying to find out a simple tutorial explaining how to make a simple app using ember cli for treating a basic json file...I've read www.ember-cli.com of course, they explain a lot things but..I don't know how to proceed.
Is there a basic example explaining (dummies level) how you make a simple app that parses a json response?
I've used the RESTAdapter, I have build muy model but I don't really know how to make in order to send a kind of response to my template..

this is my **persons.js** file under **app/adapters** folder

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({  
    host: 'http://localhost:8000/persons',
   namespace: 'person'
});



export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

this is my **persons.js** model file under **app/model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  occupation: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This is my handlebars template **persons-tmp.hbs** file under **app/templates/components**

```
<ul>    
{{#each model as |item|}}
        <li>{{item.firstName}}</li>
      {{/each}}
</ul>
```

My **persons.js** file undert the folder **app/routes**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({  
        model: function() {
            return this.store.findAll('persons');
        }
    })
```

and finally the json response of the call to http://localhost:8000/persons:

```
"person": {
    "firstName": "Barack",
    "lastName": "Obama",
    "occupation": "President"
  }
```

I don't know why but I don't get any data on my template result--..

I also have tried the [twilio tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/getting-started-with-ember-js-2-0-using-ember-cli.html) (wich is one the best that I've found) ...but even this doesn't work

Sorry for the simplicity!

Comment: I would really recommend this for beginners of Ember-CLI: http://www.programwitherik.com/a-beginners-guide-to-ember-cli/.  It is a tough framework to learn, but is arguably the best for large scale web apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your template will not know about the model unless it is defined in your route.  Each page of your application should have a corresponding route (if you are using default structure, look in app/routes/yourRoute.js; if you are using pod structure app/your-route/route.js).  This is the file where you would hit your model.

If your model is called `accounts`:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('accounts'),
  }
});
```

Now your template for that route will have access to the model, which comes from your store.  Your store uses your adapter to hit the API.  If results aren't being returned correctly, make sure the RESTAdapter is serializing the data correctly.

**Your model**

When you generate your model in ember-cli, you should have entered `ember generate model accounts` into your terminal/command line.  This would create: `app/model/accounts.js` or (if using pod stucture) `app/accounts/model.js`.

This model will automatically look to `app/adapters/accounts.js` if it is there, otherwise it will default to `app/adapters/application.js`.  However, you list a `main.js` file--which means you are most likely writing this all manually and not using the command line.

If you are using Ember-CLI, you should really try generating everything through the command line/terminal rather than manually adding it yourself.  The resolver may give you some unexpected behavior if you are within in an Ember-CLI application.

For the adapter, if your `model` is called `names`, it will automatically append it to the namespace/host defined in your application adapter.  If you need to get info from `superapi.com/names/accounts` for instance:

```
export default RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://superapi.com',
  namespace: 'names'
});
```

If you look in your console, it should tell you the domain you are trying to hit. If you are running on localhost and trying to hit an outside source, your browser may be stopping you for security reasons.

**Serving your API locally**

If your API is hosted locally on a different port (i.e. in `localhost:8000`) you can run your ember server through a proxy.  When you run your server through the command line you can enter `ember server --proxy http://localhost:8000`.  The benefit of doing this is that you can now update the `host` of your adapter to `api/v1` if your api is normally `localhost:8000/api/v1`.

**Async Data & Promise Chaining**

If you aren't getting any errors, Ember is most likely not serving the data fast enough--i.e. it is loading the template before the data is returned from your API.  This is when you want to do an RSVP on your model (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/asynchronous-routing/)

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({  
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          this.store.findAll('persons')
        })
    },
    setupController: function(controller, hash) {
       Ember.setProperties(controller, hash);
    }
});
```

Essentially, it will tell your app not to load certain things until the data has been returned from your API--i.e. it promises to do something upon fetching the data and not before.

Comment: 1.Is there a way to see if the adapter ir serializing corretcly the data?
2. How you name your model? only by calling the js file accounts ?

Thanks !

Comment: fabulous and very well explained, thanks @user821247

Comment: "If you look in your console, it should tell you the domain you are trying to hit. If you are running on localhost and trying to hit an outside source, your browser may be stopping you for security reasons."
That means that if my json response is on my localhost I'm gonna get blocked.?
`export default RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http:localhost:8000',
  namespace: 'names'
});`

Comment: Also..do I have to put my REST adapter into a js under the adapter folder?
How do I generate an adapter using the console?

Comment: How are you running your server? `ember server` in your command line?  You can do `ember s --proxy http://localhost:8000` if that is where you will be serving your data/api.  This should get around the browser blocking it.

Comment: I don't think that this a browser blocking problem..I think I have a problem of understanding how ember works.
I have updated the code of the answer, I think that you will see whee is the problem

Comment: @RadioPalmeres Try using an RSVP hash (explained above).